# Specifiy Connection String When Publishing Web

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish

I have a web site I am building where I need to deploy to two environments: stage and prod.

I have three connection strings specified in my web.config.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyWebAppWaitWebDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyWebAppWaitWeb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="MyWebAppConnection_Stage" connectionString="Server=StageSQL01T;Database=MyWebAppWaitWeb;User Id=foo;Password=bar" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="MyWebAppConnection_Prod" connectionString="Server=ProdSQL01;Failover Partner=ProdSQL02;Database=prd_SP_ExternalData;User Id=foo;Password=bar" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In the Publishing Web Wizard I am presented all three of these connection strings in the "settings" portion of the wizard.  So in this case I chose stage and un-checked the others so that I can publish to my stage server.

[image]

Upon publishing I find it added a new connection called "MyWebAppConnection_Stage_DatabasePublish"

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=MyWebAppWaitWebDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyWebAppWaitWeb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.MyWebApp" />

<add name="MyWebAppConnection_Stage" connectionString="Data Source=StageSQL01T;Initial Catalog=MyWebAppWaitWeb;User ID=foo;Password=bar" providerName="System.Data.MyWebApp" />

<add name="MyWebAppConnection_Prod" connectionString="Server=ProdSQL01;Failover Partner=ProdSQL02;Database=prd_SP_ExternalData;User Id=MyWebAppWebApp;Password=bar" providerName="System.Data.MyWebApp" />

<add name="MyWebAppConnection_Stage_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=StageSQL01T;Initial Catalog=MyWebAppWaitWeb;User ID=foo;Password=bar" providerName="System.Data.MyWebApp" />
```

Why is this 4th connection string being generated? Furthermore, how is this VS 2010 Publishing compatible with the DbContext class I have for my Entity Code-first class that specifies the connection string?

```
public class MyContextDb : DbContext
{
    public MyContextDb(): base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        Debug.Write(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
    }
...
```

I would think that I would want to use traditional web.config transformation which simply alters one connection string according to the transform file being used.