# 500 Error When Deploying MVC 4 Code First App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msdeploy

I have a MVC4 Code First web app that I am trying to deploy to a stage server (Win Svr 8, 64 bit) using Web Deploy Package from VS Ultimate 64bit.

This error seems to indicate something wrong with asp.net configured in IIS.  Numerous other posts seem to indicate that using aspnet_regiis -ir command from the following folders to insure everything is installed correctly has solved their problem.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 aspnet_regiis -ir
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 aspnet_regiis -ir

Other posts say adding this to modules in web.config has solve their problem.  I have done both and still nothing works for me.

```
runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"
```

To test that MVC operates on my stage server I have deployed a new (unaltered from the internet template) MVC 4 web app which does work.

Error Msg:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
Module ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification ExecuteRequestHandler 
Handler System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler 
Error Code 0x00000000 
Requested URL http://mytweb:80/ 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyWeb 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous
```

I can see that the code first is running properly for the membership providers as those tables seem to be setup in the database.  However, the other tables that my app creates via code-first do not exist.

Pardon the similar (unanswered) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073802/specifiy-connection-string-when-publishing-web#comment21198480_15073802) but this issues is killing us and pretty desperate at this point.

Comment: Any luck fixing this in the end? I'm having similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS >> goto Application Pools >> Find the related Application >> Right Click >> Advanced Settings >> Set the `Load User Profile` to **TRUE**. This may work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this setting has no effect.  Same error persists. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this same error message and I couldn't get any tracing or logging to happen. After days of research I realized it was an unhandled exception in Global.asax.cs. I would recommend auditing your Global.asax code to see if there is any opportunity for exceptions to happen.

Regardless, you might want to follow the best practice to handle such Application-level errors to output the last error message to a custom page:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/24395wz3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

On a database front, I have encountered issues when the database does not grant permission to the user that is logged in to the website (IUSR in case of anonymous authentication). Since you're creating tables in code, do they grant the necessary permissions to the user?